# Build SQL query for each record of a csv file

Tags: php, sql, parsing, csv

Good Day everyone,

to be honest I am stuck... I would like to ask for your help. The challenge I am facing looks like this:
1. Upload a CSV file to the server.
2. Open the CSV file.
3. Parse it, Display the data & Build a sql query for each record of the csv file.

Now, my problem is step 3. I got as far as parsing and displaying the data in a table but I fail at building the query. Any help here is appreciated!

This is the code I am using to parse the csv file and display the data. I would like to ask for your help how I should alter the code to create and execute a sql query for each record of the file.

```
if ( $file = fopen( "upload/" . $storagename , r ) ) {

            echo "File opened.<br />";

            $firstline = fgets ($file, 4096 );
            //Gets the number of fields, in CSV-files the names of the fields are mostly given in the first line
            $num = strlen($firstline) - strlen(str_replace(";", "", $firstline));

            //save the different fields of the firstline in an array called fields
            $fields = array();
            $fields = explode( ";", $firstline, ($num+1) );

            $line = array();
            $i = 0;

            //CSV: one line is one record and the cells/fields are seperated by ";"
            //so $dsatz is an two dimensional array saving the records like this: $dsatz[number of record][number of cell]
            while ( $line[$i] = fgets ($file, 4096) ) {

                $dsatz[$i] = array();
                $dsatz[$i] = explode( ";", $line[$i], ($num+1) );

                $i++;
            }

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            for ( $k = 0; $k != ($num+1); $k++ ) {
                echo "<td>" . $fields[$k] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";

            foreach ($dsatz as $key => $number) {
                //new table row for every record
                echo "Record <tr>";
                foreach ($number as $k => $content) {
                    //new table cell for every field of the record
                    echo "<td>" . $content . " </td>";
                }
            }

            echo "</table>";
        }
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        foreach ($dsatz as $key => $number) {

    // New code here -lighthart
            echo "insert into table ("
                 .implode(",", $fields)
                 .") values ("
                 .implode(",",$number).");"


            //new table row for every record
            foreach ($number as $k => $content) {
                //new table cell for every field of the record
                echo "<td>" . $content . " </td>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry but I wasn't able to get it working that way yet, I will try again tomorrow...